# make a frame inside a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hello I would like to do something like this:

[image]

The problem is the green frame. I can't get it:

Update code with almaz_from_kazan choice, still doesnt work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@color/blue"
>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/aboutTitle"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:background ="@color/red"
> 
       <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"   
         />


     //contents


         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
         />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I implement the frame 70% width, 70% height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your `content layout` with some extra vertical and horizontal `LinearLayouts` with empty `View`'s and make something like this:

[image]

Ok, here is my implementation. (but i don't think that it is the best practise because of empty view's)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.15" />

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.7"
      android:orientation="vertical">

         <View
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.15" />

         <!-- content layout -->
         <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.7"
           android:background="#0f0" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.15" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="0.15" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this will give you:

[image]

green area is exactly 70% of screen width and 70% of screen height

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create the red squire and set padding for the distance towards the inner green squire

sample with fixed padding:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleLabel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/aboutTitle"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    /> 

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding ="30dp"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@color/green">

    <!-- contents green squire -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

edit try to impliment weightsum tag, sample:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:weightSum="7"
    android:gravity="center">
    <!-- contents green squire -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will not give you a border of 30% but 30dp.